# Pod in Kubernetes not removed when psql command finished

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, psql

In Kubernetes, I want start a PostgreSQL pod, create database, user and grant all privileges to the database to the user. So I came up with the following command:

```
kubectl run somepod --rm -i --restart=Never --image postgres:alpine --tty -- psql "postgresql://postgres:somepass@localhost" -c "CREATE DATABASE testdb" -c "CREATE USER myUser WITH PASSWORD 'password'" -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO myUser"
```

It already works, but unfortunately the pod isn't terminated after the command. In Kubernetes, the pod is still alive and it's status is "Succeeded". I already tried adding `-c '\q'` to the command line because I assumed that psql is still running, but it didn't helped. Any ideas how I can remove the pod after the command has been succeeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
kubectl run  test4 -i --tty --image=postgres --restart=Never --rm  --command -- echo "hello"
hello
pod "test4" deleted
```

In your example, you are just executing a command in a running container, where postgres is started already.

You need to overvrite the command which is executed when the container is started.

Executing your command: (the error comes only because i didnt install any postgres)

kubectl run  test4 -i --tty --image=postgres --restart=Never --rm  --command -- psql "postgresql://postgres:somepass@localhost" -c "CREATE DATABASE testdb" -c "CREATE USER myUser WITH PASSWORD 'password'" -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO myUser"

This will work if your postgres on localhost has right credentials.

Or it will return like so, because connection couldnt be established:

```
kubectl run  test4 -i --tty --image=postgres --restart=Never --rm  --command -- psql "postgresql://postgres:somepass@localhost" -c "CREATE DATABASE testdb" -c "CREATE USER myUser WITH PASSWORD 'password'" -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO myUser"
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
pod "test4" deleted
```

But however the pod is beeing deleted.

Hint to not doing that always manually , you can put a initContainer in your deployment or execute a job. Both with same image and Command.